# "pre" tag not shrinking. Not showing Horizontal scroll Bar

Tags: css, wordpress, genesis

I show a lot of code on my site. The rest of my site is responsive, but the "pre" tag refuses to shrink and display horizontal scroll bars. Here's a screenshot of my content getting cut off due to the long "pre" tag at the top:

[image]

I'm using overflow:horizontal, but you can see in the example that it doesn't work. Here's the actual link [enter link description here](http://www.webhostingshed.com/uncategorized/post-with-og_image-text.html/)

As soon as I switch my theme, it works fine! I'm using a child theme of the Genesis Framework...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to assign a width to the element, so that the content can overflow.
Try setting `width: 100vw`, for example, and it will work.

If your pre tag has margin/padding to the sides for your actual website layout, try `width: calc(100vw - 40px)` whereas in this example `40px` relates to a margin of 20px to both sides. Replace it with your own actual margin/padding.

Comment: Your previous comment worked (before your edit!). You used a unit "vw" that seems to solve the problem. Setting it to "500px" simply causes a fixed width and the pre element doesn't shrink beyond that.

Change your comment back to the "vw" one and I'll mark as answered :D

Comment: I thought of percentage at first, but that wouldn't work as its parent doesn't have a fixed width and it doesn't either. `vw` seemed to cut off the phrase (wouldn't display) and also seemed like a cheap workaround. But if it works for you, then all the better. Changed it back :)

Comment: Yes, sorry, didn't notice. Original answer was `width: 100vw`.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why nobody gave the answer of:

```
pre {
   white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

It preserves the lines and words while at the same time wrapping the lines if there isn't enough space.

Comment: Wrapping lines or showing a horizontal scroll are two different behaviors.

Comment: This can look pretty ugly in some cases, not really a solution per se.

Answer (score 4):

As of 2022, you can achieve this without hard-coding widths by setting `overflow: auto` on the element you want to scroll.

Often this isn't enough, because the element has already enlarged its parent before the overflow property is checked.  So you usually have to set `overflow: auto` on a bunch of parent/grandparent/etc. elements as well, to stop them from enlarging themselves.  Normally this would mean they would also get scroll bars, but their children having `overflow: auto` prevents this (because when the children scroll, there's nothing extending beyond the parents' boundaries).

It also helps to set one of the parents to `display: flex`.

```css
div.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; /* Optional */
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

pre {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div>This text won't scroll</div>
<pre>
This is really long text that should scroll. This is really long text that should scroll. This is really long text that should scroll. This is really long text that should scroll. This is really long text that should scroll. This is really long text that should scroll. This is really long text that should scroll. This is really long text that should scroll. This is really long text that should scroll. This is really long text that should scroll. This is really long text that should scroll. This is really long text that should scroll. This is really long text that should scroll. This is really long text that should scroll. This is really long text that should scroll.
</pre>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This was killing me. Adding overflow-x-auto to all the parents was the fix I needed. Thanks so much.

Answer (score -1):

Pre tag displays preformated text, and preserves spaces and line breaks and is fixed. Declare the white-space normal or pre-wrap.

```
pre {
white-space: normal;
}
```

Comment: This simply causes the lines to break. I don't want them to break. I want them to be a full line and display a horizontal scroll bar so that the user can scroll to see the full code...

Comment: If you do white-space as normal. There's no sense of using `pre`

Comment: In the previous answer with pre-wrap you said that solved your problem, and you gave me -1. Yet, If you read my answer you would notice that I said the same thing.