# Force horizontal scrollbar in pre tag once maximum width is exceeded?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a `<pre>` tag inside a flexed container like so:

```js
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>
    Left side content
  </div>
  <div>
    <pre>
The content in here is really long and should overflow but doesn't overflow and instead takes up the space of the left side content and I can't figure out how to add scrollbars
    </pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

With CSS like so:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
.flex-container > div {
  flex: 1 0 0; /* should be same size and no shrink */
}
.flex-container pre {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

But instead, it doesn't work - the right-side content `<div>` becomes a lot larger, taking up the extra space in order to fit the contents of the `<pre>` tag.

Here's a JSFiddle showcasing what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/evdj8taw/1/

As I see it, this is a combination of `max-width` and `width` not being properly enforced thanks to `flex: 1 0 0`. For example, if I instead use this CSS:

```
.flex-container > div {
  width: 300px; /* or any other static width for that matter */
}
```

It would work fine - but obviously that's not what I am trying to achieve.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39106389/pre-tag-not-shrinking-not-showing-horizontal-scroll-bar

Answer (score 2):

You should *overflow* the parent of the `pre` tag because `pre` would preserve *whitespace* and you don't have line breaks in the text or *wrapping* - see demo below and [`updated fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/08hmp6na/):

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.flex-container>div {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  overflow: auto; /* ADDED */
}

.flex-container pre {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>
    Left side content
  </div>
  <div>
    Right side content (this works fine)
  </div>
</div>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div>
    Left side content
  </div>
  <div>
    <pre>
The content in here is really long and should overflow but doesn't overflow and instead takes up the space of the left side content and I can't figure out how to add scrollbars
    </pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Only `pre` content need to scroll**

Change your markup a bit - make your *content* wrapper a [`CSS grid container`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) and wrap your `pre` in a `div` *inside* the *content* wrapper. This ensures that your whole *content* section do not scroll - see demo below:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.flex-container>div {
  flex: 1 0 0;
}

.content {
  display: grid;
}

.pre-content {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>
    Left side content
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Right side content (this works fine)
  </div>
</div>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div>
    Left side content
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="pre-content">
      <pre>
The content in here is really long and should overflow but doesn't overflow and instead takes up the space of the left side content and I can't figure out how to add scrollbars
      </pre>
    </div>
    <div>Lorel ipsum some text here and more text is here</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, but that's not what I'm looking for, because the whole content section scrolls instead of just the `<pre>` element, which is the effect I'm looking for.