# Pre tag is not scrolling horizontal

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

```
<pre style="overflow-x: auto; width:100%">
    Will never scroll. 
</pre>

<pre style="overflow-x: auto; width:500px">
    Will scroll but is not of responsive design. 
</pre>
```

I want to have a pre-element that will be more responsive in direct relation to the parent element, but the parent element has no fixed width. Using `width:100vw` or even something like `width: calc(100vw - 300px)` is not an option because the site has too many dynamic elements. I would like to accomplish this with CSS alone. Is this an issue I am only going to be able to resolve with JavaScript?

<strike>**Update:**
It appears that `overflow-x: auto` does not work unless you use a static width. In my case everything (including parent elements) is responsive, nothing is set to a static width. I solved the problem by just using `overflow-x: scroll`</strike>

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54710368/force-horizontal-scrollbar-in-pre-tag-once-maximum-width-is-exceeded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question in incorrect in stating that width: 100% will result in never scrolling, as can be seen in the following examples. All of the pre tags have width: 100%.

You may have had an issue with width: 100vw because 100vw is not the same as 100%. 100vw is equal to the width of the viewport, but 100% width is the width of the nearest parent element. In the bottom two examples, 100% width is the width of their respective divs, and will be responsive.

```css
pre {
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

#medium-container {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px dotted red;
}

#small-container {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
}
```

```html
<pre>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</pre>

<div id="medium-container">
  <pre>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </pre>
</div>

<div id="small-container">
  <pre>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </pre>
</div>
```

Comment: I have never had these issues before, so it is a bit confusing, I have made these types of pre elements for many years. I did do a search in my scss files, I have zero use of vw, it was used in the pre tag to debug. I will continue to debug. However, You are correct about one observation, my overflow scroll worked only because I left a static fixed width in the scss, once removed, that solution no longer worked. I am at a loss as to what Is causing this. It's very frustrating as I can set pre. display: none and the page is perfect. That pre tag just forces everything to be a certain width.

Comment: I'm sorry I wish I could be more help. I could take another crack at it but I'm having difficulty understanding what behavior you're trying to accomplish. In the code snippet I created, the pre tags scale to the size of the container they are inside of properly. Is this not the goal?

Comment: Your answer was on track.  I ended up changing the core structure of the site. It was using flex for a sidebar and a content area. I changed to a block-level div with a fixed sidebar.  That change made it behave properly. It’s weird because the pre tag is nested in many other block elements that size properly. It was only the pre tag that would not downsize.  So four parents up was a flexbox that is now a block-level div and it changed the behavior. The site has a lot going on over time and more than a few hands in it - so, it works, I’m not touching it. It will remain a spaghetti mystery.